# Local Apache Server on Windows - PHP Website Connecting to Cloud SQL Postgres Database with SSL

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform

We have a Windows desktop serving an Apache2 PHP web site the currently accesses data from a local postgresql instance.  We are migrating the database to a Google SQL Postgres instance and using a public IP address with SSL encryption.

I have created the requisite certificates on Google Cloud.  The database is up and running and I have been successful in getting all Windows apps (.Net and .Net Core) to connect to the Cloud SQL database instance.

I have so far been completely stymied in getting PHP to connect to the same database.  I have tried many combinations of connection string and parms and cannot get anything to work.

Example pg_connect string (sanitized):

```
host={secret information} port=5432 dbname={secret information} user={secret information} password={secret information} sslmode=require sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem
```

client-cert.pem and client-key.pem are as generated/downloaded from Google and work fine on windows apps.  The files are saved in c:\apache24\htdocs with the remainder of my html/php sources.  I have also stored the server-ca.pem as well and tried referring to that.

I created (copied from another user - why re-invent the wheel) a sample page to test, but get nowhere.  The test page:

```
    <?php  
// Create a custom exception error handler for pg_connect
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
// Set the error handler
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

// Force output of all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Define constants
define('DB_HOST', '{secret information}');
define('DB_USER', '{secret information}');
define('DB_PASS', '{secret information}');
define('DB_NAME', '{secret information}');
define('DB_PORT', '5432');

// Connection string with SSL certificate files
$conn_str  = 'host=' . DB_HOST . ' ';
$conn_str .= 'port=' . DB_PORT . ' ';
$conn_str .= 'dbname=' . DB_NAME . ' ';
$conn_str .= 'user=' . DB_USER . ' ';
$conn_str .= 'password=' . DB_PASS . ' ';
$conn_str .= 'sslmode=require ';
$conn_str .= 'sslcert=client-cert.pem ';
$conn_str .= 'sslkey=client-key.pem ';  

// Try catch block grabbing stored exception
try {
    echo "Attempting pg_connect: " . $conn_str . "<br>";
    $conn=@pg_connect($conn_str);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Attempt Connection
$conn = pg_connect($conn_str) or die('Cannot connect to database.');

// Set SQL String
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM client'; 

// Attempt query and iterate results
if (result = pg_query($conn, $sql))
{
    while($row=pg_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}   

// Close it up
pg_close();
?>
```

The error I get using the test:

```
Attempting pg_connect: host={secret information} port=5432 dbname={secret information} user={secret information} password={secret information} sslmode=require sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem
pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate in C:\apache24\htdocs\test.php:38 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: exception_error_handler(2, 'pg_connect(): U...', 'C:\\apache24\\htd...', 38, Array) #1 C:\apache24\htdocs\test.php(38): pg_connect('host={secret information}...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\apache24\htdocs\test.php on line 38
```

Based on hints I have found elsewhere, I have tried adding the full path to the cert and key.  Tried including the server-ca.pem and sslpassword parameters.

I would be eternally grateful for some new ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with how I was typing the full path to the cert and key.  The differences between Windows and 'nix paths.

Prefixing the paths as:

```
c://apache24/htdocs/
```

got everything working correctly.

Damn `/ \` issue.